# append a href tag to div in jQuery with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
var customlink= "<div style='text-align:left;'>some text is here";

customlink+="<a href='#' title='test link' class='class1' onclick='show('"+val1+"','"+val2+"','"+val3+"')';></a></div>"
```

When using the above code to create the hyperlink with dynamic value then hyperlink not created with dynamic values in single quotes. it give me the below result.

```
<a href="#" title="test link" class="class1" onclick="show(" 4','4','4')';=""></a>
```

what should I need to change in the above code?

Comment: Do you want to change href tag, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the use of quotes within the arguments of the method call. You need to escape them using the `\` character:

```js
var val1 = 1;
var val2 = 2;
var val3 = 3;
var customlink = '<div style="text-align:left;">some text is here <a href="#" title="test link" class="class1" onclick="show(\'' + val1 + '\',\'' + val2 + '\',\'' + val3 + '\')";>Link...</a></div>';

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = customlink;

function show(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Better yet avoid the problem entirely and improve the code quality by using `data` attributes along with an unobtrusive event handler:

```js
let val1 = 1;
let val2 = 2;
let val3 = 3;

let customlink = `<div style="text-align: left;">some text is here <a href="#" title="test link" class="class1" data-val1="${val1}" data-val2="${val2}" data-val3="${val3}">Link...</a></div>`;

let div = document.querySelector('div');
div.innerHTML = customlink;

div.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', e => {
  var elData = e.target.dataset;
  console.log(elData.val1);
  console.log(elData.val2);
  console.log(elData.val3);
});
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I have used the \ character in starting & end but forget to add with each parameter. now problem solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.

```js
function generatetage(val1,val2,val3){
  var customlink= "<div style='text-align:left;'>some text is here";

  customlink+=`<a href='#' title='test link' class='class1'    onclick="show('${val1}','${val2}','${val3}')">testlink</a></div>`
  document.getElementById("tagarea").innerHTML=customlink;
}
```

```html
<div id="tagarea"></div>
<button onclick="generatetage(4,4,4)">testButton</button>
```